# Magento 2.4.3 - Checkout JS knockout error - renderReCaptcha

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, knockoutjs, knockout

We upgrade to Magento 2.4.3 and now face the following JS knockout error in the checkout:

```
TypeError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function (){return renderReCaptcha() }"
Message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.settings.rendering')
```

We disabled the Magento CAPTCHA on storefront, the default Magento module.

Solution, update `Magento_RecaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCapthca.js`

```
if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
    return; 
}
parameters = _.extend(
    {
        'callback': function (token) { // jscs:ignore jsDoc
            this.reCaptchaCallback(token);
            this.validateReCaptcha(true);
        }.bind(this),
        'expired-callback': function () {
            this.validateReCaptcha(false);
        }.bind(this)
    },
    this.settings.rendering
);
```

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/348821/82670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "error" occurs if you have ReCaptcha disabled. To get rid of it you can either enable ReCatptcha for checkout, rewrite the file which throws this error for proper error handling or just ignore it - **it doesn't actually break anything**.

```
parameters = _.extend(
    {
        'callback': function (token) { // jscs:ignore jsDoc
            this.reCaptchaCallback(token);
            this.validateReCaptcha(true);
        }.bind(this),
        'expired-callback': function () {
            this.validateReCaptcha(false);
        }.bind(this)
    },
    this.settings.rendering
);
```

`this.settings` is undefined if ReCatptcha is disabled so reading the `rendering` property obviously throws an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What is the exact file and what should be the correct way of rewriting so the error message disappear?

Comment: You should only rewrite the `initCaptcha` function using a mixin. The file is `Magento_RecaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCapthca.js` - read more https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html#examples

You should just add a check in the beginning, something like `if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { return; }`

Comment: after adding the fixed proposed, now I am getting this js error: `Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return (!getIsInvisibleRecaptcha()) }"`, any clue ? :) thanks

Comment: Modify one more method to return  , getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { return; }
                return this.settings.invisible;
            },

Comment: Your answer show us what is the true issue here and so we can custom code by our self, but I've create an full answer for some one who lazy to write their our code, please check, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

This is a known core bug.

Please see here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33741 
The fix itself: https://github.com/magento/security-package/pull/302/files

Answer (score 4):

Update answer for Zankar and jkulig:

This is correct and full answer:

1. Create new module:

***app/code/Vendor/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/registration.php***

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ReCaptchaFrontendUi',
    __DIR__
);
```

***app/code/Vendor/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/etc/module.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ReCaptchaFrontendUi" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

2. Create mixin js to override this file (*Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha*):

***app/code/Vendor/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha': {
                'Vendor_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

***app/code/Vendor/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/view/frontend/web/js/reCaptcha-mixin.js***

```
define(function() {
    'use strict';

    return function(target) {
        return target.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                return this._super();
            },

            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                return this._super();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Override File : *vendor/magento/module-re-captcha-checkout/Block/LayoutProcessor/Checkout/Onepage.php***

*Find below line:*

```
['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['place-order-recaptcha'])) {
```

*replace to*

```
['payment']['children']['beforeMethods']['children']['place-order-recaptcha-container']['children']
['place-order-recaptcha'])) {
```

Comment: But it's not good way to direct change in vendor - It's override the file as custom module

Answer (score 1):

Create a mixin in your module or theme (eg. `Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha-mixin.js`), reference it in local requirejs-config.js and add the following code:

```
define([], function() {
    'use strict';

    return function(Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }

                this._super();
            },
            
            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                
                return this._super();
            }
        });   
    }
});
```

This fixed the error for me and it should not cause conflicts with future upgrades.

Comment: Your answer make an issue: `this.super(); is not a function`. I've create an update answer, please check, thanks.

Comment: Also, you missing all the `define()` params.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue in my environment, So I created a module and fixed that issue.

**Step1:** Create `registration.php` file.

**app/code/VendorName/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ReCaptchaFrontendUi',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step2:** Create module.xml

**app/code/VendorName/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/etc/module.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ReCaptchaFrontendUi" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step3:** Create `requirejs-config.js` file

**app/code/VendorName/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha' : {
                'VendorName_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptcha-mixin' : true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Step4:** Create mixin file `reCaptcha-mixin.js`

**app/code/VendorName/ReCaptchaFrontendUi/view/frontend/web/js/reCaptcha-mixin.js**

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/registry',
        'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/reCaptchaScriptLoader',
        'Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi/js/nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer'
    ], function (Component, $, ko, _, registry, reCaptchaLoader, nonInlineReCaptchaRenderer) {
        'use strict';

    return function(Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initCaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }

                this._super();
            },
            
            getIsInvisibleRecaptcha: function () {
                if (typeof this.settings === 'undefined') { 
                    return; 
                }
                
                return this.settings.invisible;
            }
        });   
    }
});
```

**Step 5:** Run all the magento command, Issue will be fixed.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in 2.4.4 check: https://github.com/magento/security-package/pull/302#issuecomment-1016582416

**I just tested in 2.4.5, and I can confirm it is solved in this version**. I did not test it in 2.4.4.