# Upgrade Issues Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2

I upgraded magneto 2.4.3p-1 after i place the order am getting an error
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\UiConfigResolverInterface in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:

How to fix those

Comment: Might be related to this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347942/magento-2-4-3-checkout-js-knockout-error-renderrecaptcha

Comment: Hello, i did what they said but still am facing same issues

Comment: Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ReCaptchaUi\Model\UiConfigResolverInterface in /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace: